# If $S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ then $A$ is open in $S$ if and only if $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that $A \subset S \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$ Show:
>
> If $S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ then $A$ is open in $S$ if and only if $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose that $A$ is open in $S,$ then $S$ inherits the subspace topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ so we have $A = T \cap S$ where $T$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Now $A$ is the intersection of two open sets, and so $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

How do we prove the converse direction $(\Leftarrow)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, then $A = A \cap S$ is open in $S$.

Note that this doesn't depend on $S$ being open in $\mathbb R^n$ at all. Whenever you have $A\subseteq S\subseteq X$, $A$ open in $X$, you also have $A$ open in $S$. The other direction however (the one you already proved), does indeed depend on $S$ being open in $X$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now